# 'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables::class, not found on live server laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I got following error on liver server but on local server its work fine

```
'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables::class,
```

Comment: Did you install composer packages on your live server?

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: @Jerodev Yes  installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case problem try:

```
'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
```

Comment: Nice catch. (4 more to go...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is case of letters:

```
'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class
```

Linux filesystem is case-sensitive, and you have 3 times`Datatables` instead of `DataTables`